# Algorithm used in KNeighborsClassifier with sparse input?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For classification algorithm `KNeighborsClassifier` what does fitting on a sparse input mean?

Does it mean if I have `x_train` and `x_test` as sparse csr matrix and If I fit on `x_train` and don't specify algorithm it will automatically choose brute? can anyone clear this confusion.

> algorithm : {‘auto’, ‘ball_tree’, ‘kd_tree’, ‘brute’}, optional
> Algorithm used to compute the nearest neighbors:
>
> Note: fitting on sparse input will override the setting of this parameter,
> using brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means that if the input is sparse, whichever value passed to the argument `algorithm` will be ignored and brute force algorithm will be used (which is equivalent to `algorithm='brute'`)

Comment: I have my x_train as csr matrix then I did `knn.fit(x_train, y_train)` and I didn't specify any algorithm. So does this mean it will automatically be choosed as `brute`?

Comment: From what the documentation states, yes.

Comment: What is the reason/intuition that an algorithm different than 'brute' can't be used when fitting on sparse input?

Comment: @hipoglucido It is not that no algorithm but `brute` can be used on sparse data, it is that none of the scikit-learn implemented algorithm but `brute` would give accurate results in the case of sparse data so the library automatically saves the user from making the mistake. Both the ball-tree and kd-tree algorithms have the underlying assumption that the data is not sparse, they have never been designed to work with such data. Brute force however, will typically work with any kind of data but can be slow (which is less of an issue when there's less data or that data is sparse).